# Getting Virtual machines location for classic VM's from Azure using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

i wish to get the location of the VM for classic machines from powershell. I tried all the methods from `Get-AzureVM`, but couldn't get the location.

I am able to get locations of the VM's from `Get-AzureRmVm` (ARM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not directly use `Get-AzureVM` to get VM location. You could use `get-AzureVM | Get-Member` to check. There is no `location` in the result.

For classic VMs, you could get VM location by using the following cmdlet.

```
$vm=Get-AzureVM -ServiceName shui -Name shui
$uri=$vm.VM.OSVirtualHardDisk.MediaLink.AbsoluteUri
Get-AzureDisk | Where-Object {$_.MediaLink -eq $uri}| Select-Object Location
```

This is my result.

[image]

Comment: You could get VM OS disk firstly and get VM location with the disk uri.

Comment: The above mentioned cmdlet exposes the method 'location'. But it coming as null for all the VM's . pls help

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan The cmdlet only could list one VM location. If you want to list multi VMs, you had better use `foreach`

Comment: yah i knew that. even for one vm it is giving an null value. it is returning other values like diskname, media link,affinity group. But Location is coming Null

Comment: Hi, what is your Azure version? My version is 3.7.0. You could check version with `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: Hi, what is the result `$uri=$vm.VM.OSVirtualHardDisk.MediaLink.AbsoluteUri` and `Get-AzureDisk`?

Comment: Hi, My version is 3.3.0. can u tell me how do i update my version, so that i can the cmdlets in the same version as urs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138284/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-venkatakrishnan).

Comment: You could download the latest version from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases). You could download 3.7 version.

Comment: Thanks mate. it helped

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to get the location of an ASM model Virtual machine is to use the location of the service of the respective VM's

We can get the location of the service by using `Get-AzureService | select-object Location`

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you should call `Get-AzureSubscription` and select your subscription name:

```
Get-AzureSubscription | Select SubscriptionName
```

Confirm it's correct and not the default:

```
Get-AzureSubscription -Current
```

Then you can run the following:

```
Get-AzureVM -Name "VM Name" | Select-Object name,instancesize,location
```

Further information can be found [here](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/09/connecting-powershell-to-your-azure-subscription/)

Comment: i have executed the above command . But in the location columns its showing null. I have tried this earlier and it is not working
Pls help with some other approach

Click the below link to see the output

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unlX.png